# How to bundle several transactions into one?

Tags: api, rpc

How can i bundle several transactions intro one to avoid multiple posts to the RPC API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an endpoint at `/v1/chain/push_transactions` which takes a payload that is a JSON array of the same JSON transactions you would send to `/v1/chain/push_transaction` and returns a JSON array of the results you would get back from the individual calls.

Comment: follow up question: will that save the network resources? Will it be more efficient to aggregate and push several transactions in a mini batch? Should we design apps to do this from a centralized server?

Comment: It will save some overhead at the HTTP layer by removing redundant headers.  Additionally, for endpoints that support transport encoding this would allow gzip/deflate to be more efficient.   It's probably good practice but, it's not a whole lot more efficient yet.